# ¿Cómo proyectar solo algunas propiedades de una consulta LINQ?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, entity-framework-6

Hola estoy trabajando con Entity Framework Code First, el entorno es escritorio(Windows Forms) y mi consulta es la siguiente.

Necesito cargar un DataGridView con tan solo dos propiedades, id y descripción ¿se puede hacer este select con linq?

La idea es cargar solo esas dos propiedades de la entidad, no traerme toda la entidad completa.
¿como se puede hacer mediante linq, usando IEnumerable para traer una lista?

```
public IEnumerable<Proveedor> GetProveedor()
{
    //TO DO....
}
```

Es solo una query que con lo que me ofrece Leandro ya esta solucionado, solo que quería evitar crear una clase ProveedorExtend donde ponga mis propiedades ProveedorId, RazonSocial Con esto lograría solucionar que no me traiga el resto de columnas al DGV

Comment: Hola Pedro, por favor comparte tu código para que te podamos dar una solución mas exacta a tu problema.

Comment: Siempre es bueno compartir el código, de esta manera Leandro ya puede editar su respuesta y colocar el código relevante a tu pregunta, en lugar de usar nombres genéricos como `xxClass` en luar de `Proveedor` por ejemplo

Comment: Verifica la respuesta de Weimar, te evita crear la clase, que es lo que quieres

Comment: @Luis Lamento no a ver sido muy explicito, pero lo que quería evitar era no crear una clase extend por cada entidad de negocio y solo cree una clase UniversalExtend con dos propiedades la cual me sirve para cualquier entidad. Usando la clase de cualquier entidad me traería toda la entidad por eso que uso esa técnica, la clase extend se convierte en una clase genérica. Igualmente gracias por tu observación.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**>>necesito cargar un DataGridView con tan solo dos propiedades id y descripción, se puede hacer este select con linq?**

podrias definir estos campos en el `select` de linq

```
List<xxClass> result = (from item in db.Entidad
                       select new xxClass(){
                           id = item.Id,
                           descripcion = item.descripcion
                       }).ToList();
```

por supuesto define la clase con estas dos propiedades

```
public class xxClass{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string descripcion {get;set;}
}
```

el [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)<> implementa  `IEnumerable<>`

**>>¿no es necesario hacer una clase extend con esas dos propiedades? es mas eso es lo que quiero evitar.**

podrias aplicar herencia entre las clases

```
public class xxClassBase{
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public string descripcion {get;set;}
}

public class xxClass : xxClassBase {
      public int Prop1{get;set;}
      public string Prop2{get;set;}
}
```

En EF mapeas la entidad completa, pero cuando realizas el linq solo recuperas las dos que son de utilidad

Tambien podrias implementar

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Dividir Tabla (Table Splitting)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/09/entity-frameworkcode-first-dividir.html)

con esto puedes separar la tabla en entidades diferenciando las propiedades.

Comment: ya tengo la entidad con las propiedades de esa entidad que son como ocho propiedades, ¿no es necesario hacer una clase extend con esas dos propiedades? es mas eso es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Podrias reusar la misma entidad cargando solo 2 propiedades de las 8, pero cuando lo asignes al grid vas a ver todas las propiedades como columnas. Tambien podrias aplicar herencia entre las clases

Comment: me parece interesante tu técnica se crean dos clases y representa una sola en la base de datos, lo que me llama la atención en que momento llamaría al método DeleteIncludeExtended, en mi caso este método seria sin parámetro ya que yo necesito una lista public EmployeeExtended GetExtendedById(int id)

Comment: puedes definirlo sin parametros si es que no defines ningun filtro, o sea en el linq no tendrias el "where". cuando cargas el grid lamarias un metodo que devuelve el Employee y cuando necesitas la entidad completa llamas otro que devuelve EmployeeExtended. Por lo general el primero seria sin parametros, como en el ejemplo que no carga la imagen cuando se lista en el grid

Comment: Leandro cuando mi clase ProveedorExtend hereda de Proveedor estoy ocultando ProveedroId y RazonSocial de mi clase Proveedor

Comment: Tendria que eliminar en mi clase base Proveedor las propiedades ProveedorId, RazonSocial?, sería valido?

Answer (score 3):

Si es posible. Puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente, teniendo en cuenta que en este ejemplo asumo que te vas conectar a los datos directamente desde la capa de presentación (o sea desde tu formulario).

Esta es la clase de la cual se desean obtener los datos

```
public class Persona
{ 
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Nombre { get; set; } 
   public int Edad { get; set; } 
   public string Direccion { get; set; } 
}
```

Y con Linq puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
 using (var db = new PersonaContext()) 
 {
    var query = (from p in db.Persona select new {p.Id, p.Nombre}).ToList();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
 }
```

Comment: Yo creo que esta es la mejor respuesta, ya que en la pregunta se pide no crear ninguna clase para la proyección, y con tipos dinámicos se puede.